# Python Programming Dice Game?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to come up with a simulation for the Pig dice game. I want it to simulate for the number of games the user wants(each game to 100 points) and report the average points and percent wins for each player. My program is running but it is only running for one game. I think there is something wrong with my loop but i cannot tell. Thank you for your help and time here is my program:

```
from random import randrange    # Use "randrange(1, 7)" to get a random
                                # number between 1 and 6.

# Takes one turn in the game of pig.  Keeps rolling until either
# the holdAmount is reached or a pig (1) is rolled.  Returns the
# score accumulated during the turn.
def takeTurn(holdAmount):
    totalScore = 0
    while totalScore < holdAmount:
        rollValue = randrange(1,7)
        if rollValue == 1:
            totalScore = 0
            break
        else:
            totalScore = totalScore + rollValue
    return totalScore 

    # Start with turn score equal to 0.  Repeatedly roll die, adding
    # roll value to score each time, until score reaches holdAmount.
    # If at any time a pig (1) is rolled, set score to 0 and end the
    # turn early.


# Tests the takeTurn function.
def main():
    first = eval(input("How many points should the first player try for in each turn?"))
    second =  eval(input("How many points should the second player try for in each turn?"))
    games = eval(input("How many games should be simulated?"))
    firstScore = 0
    secondScore = 0
    turnCount = 0
    score = 0
    score1 = 0
    won = 0
    won1 = 0
    for i in range(games):
        while firstScore < 100 and secondScore < 100:
            firstScore = takeTurn(first) + firstScore
            secondScore = takeTurn(second) + secondScore
            turnCount = turnCount + 1
        if firstScore >= 100:
            won = won + 1
        elif secondScore >= 100:
            won1 = won1 + 1
        score = score + firstScore
        score1 = score1 + secondScore
    percent = won / games
    percent1 = won1 / games
    points = score / games
    points2 = score1 / games
    print("The average points for player one is",points)
    print("The percent of games won for player one is",percent)
    print("The average points for player two is",points2)
    print("The percent of games won for player two is",percent1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was confused for a while when I first looked at this. The reason is that each game ends with the same score since you do not reset the firstScore, etc. values each time. If you set each of those to 0 at the beginning of your for loop, you won't have any problems.

To be more specific, if you move firstScore, secondScore, and turnCount inside your for loop at the very top of it, the code runs properly.

Comment: Thank you so much meem i figured it out appreciate it.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad to have been of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to gain a better understanding of what your program is doing is to add some print statements at looping and branching points.

A more advanced technique is to trace through the program using [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#module-pdb).

Comment: I am not getting a error in my program i just cant get it to run for more then one game. Although it might be running for more than one game but only counting the last game.

Comment: That sounds like an initialization problem.  Be sure to reset all the variables between successive runs.  Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need `firstScore` and `secondScore` inside your for-loop.